# Errror 404 in httpmodule on IIS6 asp.net 3.5

Tags: asp.net, webforms, iis-6, http-status-code-404, httpmodule

I have created a simple URL rewrite module in an asp.net 3.5 webforms website. The module redirects to /default.aspx using this code :

```
HttpApplication app = (HttpApplication)source;

HttpContext ctx = app.Context;

ctx.RewritePath("~/default.aspx");

return;
```

Locally on vs2010 it works fine (it redirects all requests). On the server it gives me error 404 when request file does not exist else if the request points to an existing page it redirects fine. Can you please help me find what is the problem that gives me 404 errors ?

**SOVLED :** The problem with IIS6 is that it does fire an asp.net httpmodule only if the extension of the given url is .aspx.

Comment: How does your web.config looks for registering the module. IIS 6 uses a different section for this: <system.web><httpModules> instead of <system.webServer><modules>

Comment: <httpModules>
<add name="ReWrite" type="Inviart.Front.ReWrite, Inviart.Front"/>
</httpModules>

the modules is registered in httpmodules and as i said it works fine until we write on browser a valid url (if the page we request exists then it refirects to default.aspx else 404 error)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to check warning message in

```
computermanagment>>windowslog>>application
```